# What is wrong with this simple application of binary addition algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to apply a simple binary addition algorithm in Java, but I am getting errors repeatedly. Could anyone please help me. Thanks!

```
public class BasicBinaryAddition {

public static void main(String[] args)
{


int []sum = new int [3];
int []a = {0,1,0};
int []b = {1,1,0};
int carry =0;
int bitIndex;
for (bitIndex =0; bitIndex < a.length; bitIndex++)
{
int bitSum = a[bitIndex] + b[bitIndex] + carry;
sum[bitIndex] = bitSum%2;

double d = bitSum/2;   
carry = (int) Math.floor(d); 
}

sum[bitIndex] = carry;

for (int i = 0 ; i <= sum.length-1; i++)
System.out.print(sum[I]+"");
   }
  }
```

Comment: what error are you getting? add it to the question...

Comment: I believe it was ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Now, it is working OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding two 3-bit numbers could result in 4 bits. So, you should declare

```
int []sum = new int [4];
```

Also, you should use small `i` in the last `for`-loop

```
System.out.print(sum[i]+"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sum` array is too short to hold the full result. Make it length 4, this will avoid the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The way you calculate the carry could also be simplified to

```
carry = bitSum / 2;
```

This is an integer division and yields an integer result.

Answer (score 0):

You should put (sum[bitIndex] = carry) inside the loop;

```
public class BasicBinaryAddition {

public static void main(String[] args)
{


int []sum = new int [3];
int []a = {0,1,0};
int []b = {1,1,0};
int carry =0;
int bitIndex;
for (bitIndex =0; bitIndex < a.length-1; bitIndex++)
{
int bitSum = a[bitIndex] + b[bitIndex] + carry;
sum[bitIndex] = bitSum%2;

double d = bitSum/2;   
carry = (int) Math.floor(d); 
 sum[bitIndex] = carry;
}



for (int i = 0 ; i <= sum.length-1; i++)
System.out.print(sum[I]+"");
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure about what you said. I want (sum[bitIndex] = carry;) to be excuted only once. That is, the last carry value will be stored in the last place in the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework so I will just point you in the right direction.

The first problem is in your line:

```
   System.out.print(sum[I]+"");
```

You are using "I" instead of "i" so the compiler is upset that it can't find a variable "I".

The second problem is that you have an overflow problem. If you add 2 binary numbers of length 3 it is possible to have an answer that is 4 bits long.

```
   101 + 100 = 1001
```

When you perform the line: sum[bitIndex] = carry, bit index equals 3, which means the 4th item of the array sum (remember Java arrays start from index 0). However sum is declared to be of length 3, so Java's head explodes in rage that you tried to access an element of an array that is out of bounds. The answer to this problem is to declare sum to be of length 4.

Another thing that can be cleaned up are the lines:

```
double d = bitSum/2;   
carry = (int) Math.floor(d);
```

This can be simplified to:

```
carry = bitSum/2;
```

This works because carry and bitSum are both integers, so Java will perform integer division, which just ignore anything that would happen after the decimal in regular division.

Comment: No, it is not a homework. I am doing kind of self-study to get into algorithms. Thanks a lot for your valuable informative comments.